# PHP split string from end with specific pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

i have these string that have combination of hospital and cities. i want to split and get only the hospital name.

```
ABC Hospital (rawalpindi)
ABC Hospital (New) (Rawalpindi)
XYZ Hospital (old) (Lahore)
```

I want to split the string from end is such a way that output should be.

```
ABC Hospital
ABC Hospital (New)
XYZ Hospital (old)
```

Comment: Have you even tried something to solve the problem by yourself?

Comment: What's is the logic? add more information please? `(New)` and `(old)` are accepted, not the others?

Comment: @MTaqi Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing substring to make a smaller string with the last position of `" "`.

```
substr($s1, 0, strripos($s1," "));
```

With a sample code:

```
$s1 = "ABC Hospital (rawalpindi)";
$s2 = "ABC Hospital (New) (Rawalpindi)";
$s3 = "XYZ Hospital (old) (Lahore)";

echo substr($s1, 0, strripos($s1," "));
echo substr($s2, 0, strripos($s2," "));
echo substr($s3, 0, strripos($s3," "));
```

This will produce the output:

```
ABC Hospital
ABC Hospital (New)
XYZ Hospital (old)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple regex:

```
foreach(array('ABC Hospital (rawalpindi)', 'ABC Hospital (New) (Rawalpindi)', 'XYZ Hospital (old) (Lahore))') as $name){
  echo preg_replace('/(.*) \(.*/', '\1', $name) . "\n";
}
```